# Project for Html course, final project

Tags: layout, row

[example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t8Q6.jpg)  expected layout for single webpage

I am not an expert at html, I have getting by weekly with help from other students.

I have been told that I can make this with bootstrap, which is still a mystery to me.  or simple html and CSS.

I not sure where to begin, I realize that this may be simple for some, but not so simple for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

simple html and css code for layout, I can add the background and pictures.

Comment: Two days and 20 views and no one is will to help me, wow, this a really friendly community.